# Uploading to Firebase Storage with ngx-uploader

Tags: angular, file-upload, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

How can I use ngx-uploader or similar to upload images to firebase?

The main problem I am facing is that most implementations of Angular 2 uploader require a URL but I need to upload to the firebase refrence and I'm not sure how to peice this together or if it can even be done. Perhaps I'm not looking at it the right way.

I found this [script](http://www.muhammetbakan.com/angular2-ionic2-how-to-upload-and-get-image-from-firebase-storage/):

```
uploadImage(name, data) {
    let promise = new Promise((res,rej) => {
      let fileName = name + ".jpg";
      let uploadTask = firebase.storage().ref(`/teams/${fileName}`).put(data);
      uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot) {
      }, function(error) {
        rej(error);
      }, function() {
        var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
        res(downloadURL);
      });
    });
    return promise;
  }
```

This showed me I need to user the `firebase.storage().ref`

but then if I look at the [ngx-uploader documentation example](http://docs.ngx-uploader.com/) I can't figure out how I use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you followed the documentation, you are probably running this code

```
 startUpload() {
    this.inputUploadEvents.emit('startUpload');
  }
```

which will run the code that will use the url variable in the NgUploaderOptions which you don't really need if you are using firebase storage. What I did is I add the (change) event like this

```
 <input (change)="onChange($event)"
           type="file"
           class="hidden"
           ngFileSelect
           [options]="options"
           [events]="inputUploadEvents"
           (onUpload)="handleUpload($event)"
           (onPreviewData)="handlePreviewData($event)"
           (beforeUpload)="beforeUpload($event)">
```

And in the back-side

```
   onChange(event: EventTarget) {
        let eventObj: MSInputMethodContext = <MSInputMethodContext> event;
        let target: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement> eventObj.target;
        let files: FileList = target.files;
        this.file = files[0];

    }
```

Now you just need to insert the this.file in the ref.put()...

Note that this is for single image only. Hope this helps.